# ActiveRecord 500 error, but fixed on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My rails site is throwing a 500 error when I add a new item to an ActiveRecord model when in production mode. In dev mode, it throws a 404. In both production and development, a simple refresh of the page solves the problem.

Here is the log.

```
2018-01-15T23:11:26.565002+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.564925 #4]  INFO -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
2018-01-15T23:11:26.563230+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.563150 #4] DEBUG -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d]    (4.3ms)  COMMIT
2018-01-15T23:11:26.565969+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.565895 #4] FATAL -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d]   
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566089+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.565970 #4] FATAL -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d] ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566091+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566092+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/views"
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566094+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566291+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.566237 #4] FATAL -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d] app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:31:in `create'
2018-01-15T23:11:26.566163+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-01-15T23:11:26.566079 #4] FATAL -- : [eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d]   
2018-01-15T23:11:26.567079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/questions" host=stclprores.herokuapp.com request_id=eb00b0fb-d0b8-4677-b952-9704b19c9f2d fwd="96.88.61.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
```

My best guess on what's happening is that the model is taking too long to update and the page is trying to pull information from the model at the same time it is trying to save it, so it returns Nil values and the page crashes. However, I could be completely wrong. Could anyone point me on the right track here. What is Rails trying to do, and how am I getting in its way?

Here is my controller:

```
def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.save 
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        redirect_to '/error/could_not_save'
    end 
end 

def index 
    @questions = Question.all 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end 
end 

def new 
    @question = Question.new 
end 

def create 
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    if @question.save
        redirect_to '/' 
    else 
        redirect_to '/error/could_not_save'
    end 
end 

def destroy
    Question.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to '/index'
end 

private
    def question_params
        params.require(:question).permit(:topic, :prompt, :correct_answer, :wrong_answer_one, :wrong_answer_two, :wrong_answer_three)
    end
```

Here is config/routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :questions

  root 'static#home'

  get '/home' => 'static#home'
  get '/error/unknown_error' => 'static#unkown_error'
  get '/error/could_not_save' => 'static#could_not_save'

  get '/:id/edit' => 'questions#edit', as: @question
  post '/index' => 'questions#update'
  get '/home' => 'questions#home'
  get '/new' => 'questions#new'
  get '/questions' => 'questions#index'
  get '/question' => 'question#index'
  post '/index/' => 'questions#create'
  get '/index' => 'questions#index'
  get '/practice' => 'questions#practice'
end
```

Comment: Can you add some code, it'd help us get a clear understanding of the issue

Comment: Can you post your questions_controller code? The problem is in the logs. Rails can't find the index action. `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /index` and also the `create` action is failing. I think we can get a better idea if you post the controller code.

Comment: It seems you map your `create` action to use GET method ( since you can **refresh to fix** ) which should be POST method. Please update the question with your `config/routes.rb` also.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my controller and routes, in relevant aspects.